# Headers for Contact Form are wrong

Tags: php, forms

I am using a simple contact form I created myself that consists of just a script (php) and a WordPress shortcode. It works fine except the headers are saying something like foo@somewebhosting.server54 instead of displaying my admin email (or my correct email). Can someone see where my mistake is? Thank you.

The two codes are here:  [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/dnJEahmK)

Comment: Please add your code directly to your question. Do not use pastebin, as pastebins can be removed, rendering your question useless for future use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'From' header is not correctly formatted so it is defaulting to servers address.

Try this...

```
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: iStudioFX <no-reply@istudiofx.com>' . "\r\n" .
```

Comment: Thanks Matt this was indeed the problem, appreciate the help.